# Prism event to respond to view being removed from region

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, unity-container

I'm using Prism to handle view navigation.

I want a view to respond to it being removed from a region `myRegion.Remove(view)`.

What is the correct way to handle this (in the view)?
Using the `Unloaded` event doesn't work and neither does `OnNavigatedFrom`.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this is by publishing and subscribing to a `CompositePresentationEvent` using the `EventAggregator`.  Alternatively, and maybe better, is to implement `IActiveAware` on your views (it's part of the `RegionManager` I believe).